# Raster land use calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to calculate the counts of each land use type based on the unique `Landuse code` from each raster dataset.

Raster dataset consists of six major land use and their unique codes are below:

1. Agriculture: Landuse code (2100, 2200, 2300, 2400)
2. Barren Land: Landuse code (7100, 7200, 7300, 7400, 7500, 7600)
3. Forest: Landuse code (4110, 4120, 4210,4220, 4230, 4311,
   4312, 4321, 4322, 4410)
4. Urban: Landuse
   code (1110, 1120, 1130, 1140, 1150, 1200, 1211, 1214, 1300, 1400, 1410, 1411, 1420)
5. Water: Landuse code (1419, 5100, 5190)
6. Wetlands: Landuse code (1461, 1711, 1750, 1850)

I have the code only for agricultural area to simply test whether the code is working or not for one category of land use.

When I ran the code neither did I get any error message nor the result for agricultural land. I know it's a pretty big description, sorry for that.

I am providing the code below:

```
 import arcpy, os    
 from arcpy import env
 #To overwrite output
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
 #Set environment settings
 env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Project-06-02-14/Landuse/New folder/Merged/Landuse_raster"
 outws="C:/Subhasis/Project-06-02-14/Landuse/New folder/Merged/Landuse_raster/Table"
 inraster = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "GRID")

 for i in inraster:
     flds = ("VALUE", "COUNT")  
     dct = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(i, flds)}
     Agriculture=[]
     Barrenland=[]
     Forest=[]
     Urban=[]
     Water=[]
     Wetland=[]
     for j in dct:
         if (dct.keys()==2100) or (dct.keys()==2200) or (dct.keys()==2300) or (dct.keys()==2400):
             Agriculture.append(dct.values())
             print Agriculture
         else:
             break
```

Answer (score 1):

dct.keys() will return a list of all the keys in the dictionary. When you do dct.keys()==2100, you are asking it if some list is equal to some integer - which will never evaluate to true. You won't get an error because it just evaluates to False each time and keeps checking further down the line.

Try something like:

```
    for key in dct.keys():
       if (key==2100) or (key==2200) or (key==2300) or (key==2400):
              Agriculture.append(dct[key])
```

Comment: @papadoo Thank you very much! I changed the code and rerun it. Still neither got an error message nor the value for agriculture

Comment: Are your landuse codes stored as strings? If so, make sure you are checking against strings and not integers. i.e. key=="2100"